# Assigning "aspect fill" option for background image of uibutton Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

We can set the **image** of the button to be of aspect fill by :

```
imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
```

but since I am dealing with the **background** image, I'm not sure how to access contentMode for the **background** image.

I know that instead of doing so, I can create a custom class where the image can be centered with the button text centered on top, then set the imageview as aspect fill with the above code, but that seems like a lot more work to achieve the same result.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

It's been a long time since question asked but anyone who wonder,If you set your button image using setImage() it will show the image with its width and height no matter you scale, but If you set using setBackgroundImage() It will be just fine,didn't even need to scale

Comment: This does not work for me. For me it is scaled to fill the whole button.

Answer (score 2):

For whoever stumbles across this:

The `UIImageView` that contains `backgroundImage` is not publicly accessible. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton, there is no such property. I do not why Apple protected that.

## First solution

However you can filter your `UIButton` for all the `UIImageView`s and set their property to `.scaleAspectFit`:

```swift
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        button
            .subviews
            .filter { $0 is UIImageView }
            .forEach { $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit }
    }
```

## Second solution

The first solution could possibly conflict with any other `UIImageView`s you have in your `UIButton`. So you could also filter only for the exact background image:

```swift
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "backspace-button")
        let backgroundImageView = button
            .subviews
            .filter { $0 is UIImageView }
            .first(where: { ($0 as? UIImageView)?.image == backgroundImage}) as? UIImageView
        backgroundImageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }
```

I would **not** recommend to access the `backgroundImageView` by its array index. There is no guarantee that this order will be like that forever.